# IE8-compatible tabs

Tags: library, javascript, css, internet-explorer

I am looking for a responsive tab Javascript/CSS library which works on IE8. It should change to an accordion style (but I will settle for anything right now)  when under, say 768px.

I have checked 10+ libraries and none worked in IE8. The solution should be similar to:

1. [Responsive Tabs (jellekralt)](https://github.com/jellekralt/Responsive-Tabs)
2. [Easy Responsive Tabs to Accordion](http://webthemez.com/demo/easy-responsive-tabs/Index.html#ChildVerticalTab_11)
3. [Responsive Tabs (petelove.com)](http://www.petelove.com/responsiveTabs/)
4. [tabby](https://github.com/cferdinandi/tabby/)

I have seen on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Merri/pen/bytea) some which claims to work well, but Codepen itself loads up with errors on IE8. Also I would like to have something more permanent and better supported than Codepen.